# Childhood book where young girl has visions of enslaved grandmother

Tags: identification-request

I'm trying to find a book I read at school when I was about 12. It was about a young black girl who kept having visions where she became her Grandmother at a young age, being trafficked as a slave. Like she was time travelling but specifically becoming this ancestor of hers. There was a scene with glass beads that smashed.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Literature Stack Exchange. Please read the [tag wiki](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/identification-request/info) for identification requests and add as much more information to your question as you can. For example, we don't know when you were 12; it could have been two years ago or twenty or more. Adding pertinent details like the approximate year when you read the book, what you remember about the cover, etc. will help us identify the book. Please edit your question to add the necessary details; don't add them in comments.

Comment: I think this was a popular genre at one point. I don't remember this particular book, but remember reading stories about children cast back to their ancestors in the Salem Witch trials and due to be burned at the stake, or to concentration camps in the Holocaust.

Comment: "A Girl Called Boy" by Belinda Hurmence looks similar but no glass beads scene, it seems.